# How to fix the boot loader?

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, boot, multi-boot

I dual booted my xp installing linux mint 12.

2 days ago I downloaded the Android SDK, on Eclipse Indigo (on Linux Mint) and now I can't start Linux Mint, nor XP. I can only use XP in safe mode, I don't know if the SDK has anything to do with it.

There's something wrong with the boot loader, I guess. I might be wrong. I am able to choose which OS to boot using the grub menu but both OS won't work, the PC will somehow freeze or shutdown, I don't know how to describe it properly.

Comment: linux is my default boot loader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just to close the topic, it was a vga problem, i had to buy another one

Answer (score 0):

My hint would be to use the cd of Mint to reinstall grub, I would also follow the tutorial this girl says on how to do that properly.
[How to reinstall Grub2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gl8mfpZuDiM)

Answer (score 0):

Try entering these commands in the Command prompt by inserting your Windows 7 Installation or Repair Disc:

- BootRec.exe /fixmbr
- BootRec.exe /fixboot